# ELASTIC SEARCH - exclude IP-Address from a rule

Tags: regex, elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elastic-stack

I need help to exclude an IP# in a rule.

This rule watches for firewall_rejects. I have started with this:

```
filter:
- regexp:
** ip_address: "^(?!192.168.0.2).*$"**
```

I do not need alertings or emails from the IP# 192.168.0.2 in this rule, what should I do?

Comment: Try `@&~(192\.168\.0\.2)` if it is ElasticSearch.

Answer (score 0):

Using a [query DSL Regexp Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.3/query-dsl-regexp-query.html) it should look like this to match "everything except" your IP.

```
{
    "regexp": {
        "ip_address": {
            "value": "@&~(192\.168\.0\.2)",
            "flags": "ANYSTRING"
        }
    }
}
```